# Python question what does this return entail

Tags: python, arrays, return

Doing a leetcode problem #198 and was getting the question wrong even though on my end it was working and on paper, it was checking it out come to find out it was what I was returning.

My question is what does this mean `return ans[len(nums)-1]`

Edit: Thank you for the Help!

Comment: That returns an element from the `ans` array.  I don't know what is confusing you.  I also don't understand why you would use that to solve this problem.

Comment: It means "return the item from the list `ans` at the index that's one less than the length of the list `nums`". What part don't you understand? `len(blah)` means "get the length of `blah`". `lst[i]` means "get the item from the list `lst` at the index `i`".

Answer (score 3):

return `ans[len(nums)-1]` can be broken into a number of different parts.

`len(nums)` - This will return the length of the variable `nums`.

`-1` - The value from `len(nums)` will be subtracted by 1. This is likely done as adjustment due to lists starting counting from position 0 in Python.

`ans[value]` - this will return the item from the list `ans` in position `value`. This is calculated from `len(nums) - 1`

Finally `return` - This will return the value from a function so it can be used by the caller.

Comment: Very thorough answer, you clearly had a beginner audience in mind when writing this which is great.

Answer (score 1):

If ans and nums are each a list/array or if nums is a string, it will return the result of the length of nums minus 1 in the [] which will pull that index from the ans list.

For example:

```
ans = [apple, orange, banana, strawberry, kiwi]
nums = [house, car, tree, cat] (it could be equal to a string "food" with same result)
return ans[len(nums)-1]
```

- len(nums) is 4
- minus 1
- gives you ans[3]
- which is strawberry